# Breakpoints are not working with NativeScript and WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, nativescript

I tried to run sample project of NativeScript using WebStorm IDE. Everything is ok but breakpoints don't work. I use NativeScript plugins and this configuration:

[image]

I tried the same with VSCode and it is working there.